# SQL Injection Attack against escaping single quotes

Tags: sql, code-injection, server-side-attacks

I have been told that the method of escaping single quotes is easy to bypass in a sql injection attack. For example, if I were to have the line:

```
username='admin' and password='$password'
```

where the user types in "$password", and any single quote they type gets replaced by a double quote, could you give me an example command that would break this? I know the backslash character ( \ ) is used to escape a character, but I'm not sure how it would work out still.

Comment: The first problem you have is that you're storing passwords in plain text.  You might want to read this article: http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/

Comment: Ask him/her for a proof of concept.